# How to read data from a file having unicode in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, java-11

I have a tsv file and it contains Unicode data like *"Pär Lagerkvist's received Nobel Prize in Physics."* 
But while reading it in Java I am receiving output like 
*"P�r Lagerkvist's received Nobel Prize in Physics."*

I am using the following piece of code for the file reading

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like it's reading just fine. The problem is the terminal you're using doesn't seem to know how to *output* the Unicode.

Comment: Side note: with Java 11, you should use `try(var br = Files.newBufferedReader( Paths.get(fileName))) {  /* your code using the BufferedReader */  }` to read a UTF-8 encoded file with a `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Intellij Idea. This case, set console encoding

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

On Windows, edit `idea.exe.vmoptions` file and add the above line.

See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-output-encoding.html) for details.